# How to apply conditional formatting for independently text labels on a QGIS layout

Tags: qgis, layouts, conditional

From a layout in which I use two independent text labels, as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

This text labels use the following expressions that make a calculation on two different layers:

```
[%format_number(aggregate('DELIC_2020','sum',"PROCEDIMENT"),1)%]
[%format_number(aggregate('DELIC_2021','sum',"PROCEDIMENT"),1)%]
```

Is there any option or way to format the style of these two text labels, comparing both values and colouring it in green the maximum one and in red the minimum one?

[image]

Comment: To clarify @JGH 's approach, the comparison between the two layer values should be made directly, rather than comparing content in the text boxes. There is no way at present for the expression builder to extract the contents of a text box item in a print layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the data defined override for the label text color.
Just use an expression to compare your two value and return green or red as needed :

```
CASE
    WHEN (format_number(aggregate('DELIC_2020','sum',"PROCEDIMENT"),1)) > (format_number(aggregate('DELIC_2021','sum',"PROCEDIMENT"),1))
        THEN 'green'
    ELSE 'red'
END
```

This expression will return green (using color name, you may also use rgb or hex  code, just make sure to return it as string) when DELIC_2020 value is greater than the DELIC_2021 value and red when it's not. Adapt the expression to get the right color to the right label.

[image]